# App not working on Android AVD

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I made an app on eclipse and i wanted to test it if it works. The app is installed in the emulator but kept on failing on running. I've checked my codes and it seems that nothing's wrong with it.

Here's the error message:

```
[2012-12-01 04:05:14 - RSSReader] Android Launch!
[2012-12-01 04:05:14 - RSSReader] adb is running normally.
[2012-12-01 04:05:14 - RSSReader] Performing android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner JUnit launch
[2012-12-01 04:05:14 - RSSReader] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'emu7' is  available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2012-12-01 04:05:14 - RSSReader] Uploading RSSReader.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-12-01 04:05:17 - RSSReader] Installing RSSReader.apk...
[2012-12-01 04:05:26 - RSSReader] Success!
[2012-12-01 04:05:26 - RSSReader] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on emulator-5554
[2012-12-01 04:05:26 - RSSReader] Failed to launch test
```

and here's the exception message i get from LogCat:

```
E/StrictMode(646): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

ive been researching for hours and I haven't found any solution nor what causes this error >_<

Comment: Check logcat and see what is the exception you are getting.

Comment: Already did and it's not giving out any messages. :(

Comment: can you provide your manifest file

Comment: 11-30 20:59:29.564: E/StrictMode(646):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) found the exception :O

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt and reset the adb by

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

If you still cannot get your application to run

Goto the devices tab on eclipse and hit the drop down arrow and select `reset adb`

Window -> Show View -> Devices

Comment: where can i find the device tab?

Comment: Window -> Show View -> Devices